# Macbook 5.2 screen goes dark

Tags: macbook-pro

Can I use and external monitor even though my Macbook 5.2 screen goes dark even though I can still see images when a flashlight. The entire system works and I did bring it to Mac in Portland, Maine and the entire display would have to be replaced for $500. So can I use and external if the screen goes dark. I would like to keep this running for another year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external display, using a mini-DVI to 'whatever your monitor needs' connector... More info from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4195107

> The model 5,2 has a Mini-DVI port not a Mini DisplayPort. Depends on what input plug you'll be using on your TV. VGA, DVI, Composite or HDMI. You'll need a Mini-DVI adapter and a cable from that to your TV. Here's the various types of Mini-DVI adapters on Amazon.com http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=mini-dvi&x=9&y=13
>   (Composite is the red, white and yellow RCA plugs on your TV or red, white and S-Video plugs.)
>
> You'll also need audio cables to the TV using a 3.5mm stereo headphone jack to RCA sound plugs or a 3.5mm stereo input plug for audio. You attach it from the headphone jack of your MacBook to the appropriate audio input plugs on your TV.
>
> If you connect the MacBook using a Mini-DVI to HDMI adapter you will probably need to use external speakers or a 3.5mm stereo headphone jack to RCA sound plugs connected to a stereo system for audio if your TV doesn't have separate RCA input plugs or a 3.5mm stereo input plug for audio with the HDMI plug. The Mini-DVI to HDMI doesn't carry audio and there're no audio plugs on most TVs to work with HDMI since it's expecting audio with the HDMI. Check your TV manual though to see if it might have audio plugs that work with one of the HDMI ports.